# Trying to call another intent from a function in Amazon Alexa

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am looking to create a simple coffee ordering skill for the office. I am new to node and amazon alexa. I am using the alexa-app package. I want Alexa to respond to my response with a different question or separate intent depending on my request. What is the best way to do about this? I am having difficulty seeing how to trigger a new intent.

Example conversation flow:

Me: Alexa, start office Assitant

Alexa: How can I help?

Me: I would like order some coffees. *(or any other services)*

*New intent started based on request*

Alexa: Great, what would you like?

Comment: Maybe you should ask Alexa about ths

Comment: just create two separate  intents

Comment: Thank you for your answer @NaeemShaikh  but how do you call the second intent from the first one though with out having to invoke with the intent name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the response to "I would like to order some coffees", you can send a response to the Alexa Cloud Service specifying `shouldEndSession` as false. See the documentation on the response object [here](https://developer.amazon.com/es-mx/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-object). This will make the Echo continue to listen for a second user intent.

You can have a separate utterance which will map to an intent to order a specific sort of coffee (maybe using the [custom slot type syntax](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html#add-edit-type)):

```
SpecificCoffeeIntent I would like a {CoffeeType}, please
```

Note that you don't call this intent directly - when the user says "I would like a mocha please" in response to Alexa saying "Great, what would you like?", you'll be sent a `SpecificCoffeeIntent`. Your code can then process the intent to order coffee.

Comment: Both links were broken, I edited and fixed the first one, but I couldn't manage to get a fix to the second one. You may want to check out this link tho: https://developer.amazon.com/es-mx/docs/custom-skills/create-and-edit-custom-slot-types.html

Comment: Ah, looks like Amazon changed their URL. I updated the answer to link to the Custom Slot Type documentation.